# Change the Useragent of the OS on Firefox

Tags: firefox, user-agent

I would like to know how to temporary change the user agent string of Firefox so that it appears I'm using a different OS than I really am. There's an [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/%20addon) that changes the browser u/a but I can't find one that also changes the OS agent too. Maybe not easily possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own custom user agent string using the same addon. Just go to *Edit User Agent* then click *New*. You can get samples from this site:

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php